# ASP.NET website performance

Tags: asp.net

Does any one know if number of ascx files in an ASP.NET website (not application) has anything to do with warm up performance?

Let's say that all website pages are included into ascx files and are loaded into one page and let's say that there are more than 200 ascx files in the project.

I noticed that when the IIS restarts and the website wants to warm up, there is a good 30 seconds delay, I want to find out what are reasons for this delay.
I have checked the database calls (they are no more than 7 seconds in total).

I need to add that once the first page is loaded, reloading the same page has no delay (instantly loads).

Comment: The .ascx files are loaded dynamically or they all exist in the .aspx page and are shown / hidden?

Comment: yes they are loaded dynamically, there is only one aspx page in my project.

Comment: This behaviour is on the production server or also locally? Also, what makes you think that it is the number of .ascx files that causes that?

Comment: Does that always happen after restarting the IIS or only when you update the code? Because altering the code might result in the server recompiling the whole application on the first visit thus resulting in long loading times.

Comment: It happens whenever the IIS process needs to restart (first time or due to inactivity)

Also this is server with 2 processors and 80GB of RAM (server speed is not an issue for sure)